# I need to check url/anchor in article in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to check if my anchor still live in article.
For example i have site https://stackoverflow.com/1111 and anchor: [developer] with url to  another site.
I need to check if on site: https://stackoverflow.com/1111 still going ResponseCode 200 from [developer]

```js
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
var response_code ;
try {
response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
}
catch( error ) {
response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (ddd)./ )[1] ;
}
finally {
return response_code ;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue of your script?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this formula: =IF(COUNTIF(IMPORTXML(B2,"//a/@href"),A2)>0,"Live","Not Live")
B2 link to site with article,A2 my link from thios article.